# Store and forward using JMS topics

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I'm trying to setup store and forward in ActiveMQ. We use a JMS topic to distribute messages to multiple consumers. We have multiple brokers connected using a duplex network connector. What I want is that, if a message send to the topic on broker A and is delivered to a queue, this message is forwarded to the same queue on broker B if there is no consumer for that queue on broker A.

Therefor I have a network connector configured on broker A as shown below

```
<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector 
       name="foobar" 
       uri="static:(tcp://brokerB:61616)" 
       duplex="true" 
       networkTTL="2">
        <excludedDestinations>
            <topic physicalName=">" />
        </excludedDestinations>
    </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

However, if I use this configuration, messages never get forwarded to broker B. If I remove the `<excludedDestinations>`, messages get delivered to both the queue on broker A and broker B, thus resulting in duplication. The latter is of course not what I want.

Am I doing something wrong or is the setup I want not possible using JMS topics?

Comment: Getting the correct configuration requires answering a number of questions about your brokers and desired consumer configuration.

Comment: @Matt Pavlovich: I understand, so what do you need to know?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work for this kind of question. Getting to the right solution requires planning around the intersection of the requirements of a number of pieces: publishers, consumers, SLA, HA and message volume. Different ActiveMQ configurations work or break down depending on those factors. This is more than a "how do I get ActiveMQ to do X" question.